# How to know which view was clicked in java?

Tags: java, android

Let's say that I have two ImageViews, and I want to know which one was clicked. How do I use getView() in this case? It's should be something like that

```
  @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

        checkViewId();

        switch(id){
        case 1:
        log.d -> ("id = 1");
        }
        break;

        case 2:
        log.d -> ("id = 2");
        break;

        return true;
    }
```

How should I create this checkViewId method?

Comment: First you need to add one listener to each ImageView that can be clicked, and in each listener you write the code you want. Each ImaveView clicked will execute it's listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your activity/fragment implement the `OnClickListener` interface and add the `onClick` callback:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }


}
```

When you’re binding the views, set the listener for all of them:

```
ImageView one = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.one);
    one.setOnClickListener(this);
ImageView two = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.two);
    two.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Inside the `onClick` method create your switch:

```
switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.one:
            // add your code
            break;

        case R.id.two:
            // add your code
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```